# Delphi: Simulate key press for automation

Tags: python, delphi, keyboard, ui-automation, pywinauto

I want to change text of an edit control of an external application. The application is written in Delphi. It has several forms. I started with Python libraries `pywinauto` + `sendkeys` to test the first form `TLoginForm`. It works perfectly. Here is the pseudo code:

```
helper = pywinauto.application.Application()
hwnd = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(class_name='TLoginForm')[0]
window = helper.window_(handle=hwnd)
ctrl = window[2]   # the second control is the edit control I want to access
ctrl.ClickInput()  # focus the control
ctrl.SetEditText('Hello world')  # text can be changed expectedly
```

As the second step, I want make an UI for the automation tool. But due to lack knowledge of Python UI and considering of the complexity to distribute binary in Python, I want to do it Delphi. But the weird thing is I am not able to read/write the edit control in Delphi by using Windows apis. Here are some attempts:

```pascal
SetForegroundWindow(EditControlHandle); // Works, the application will be brought to front, the edit control will be focused

// Attempt 1: Nothing happens
SetFocus(AnotherEditControlHandle);

// Attempt 2: Nothing happens
SetWindowText(EditControlHandle, 'Hello world');

// Attempt 3: Nothing happens
SendKeys32.SendKey('Hello world', {Wait=}True); 

// Attempt 4: Nothing happens
SendMessage(EditControlHandle, Ord('H'), WM_KEYDOWN, 0);
SendMessage(EditControlHandle, Ord('H'), WM_KEYUP, 0);

// Attempt 5: AttachThreadInput will return False, the reason is "Access Denied"
FocusedThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessID(ExternalAppMainWindowHandle, nil);
if AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadID, FocusedThreadID, {Attach=}True) then
```

As it works in Python, I think I must have missed something very basic and very important. But I am now so blind to find the problem. Any hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use automation rather than faking input.

Comment: And also, if you insist on this faking input approach, you should at least include error checking. Why are you ignoring return values?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is a correct automation approach? If it is easy to implement, I'll use it for sure. And yes, you are right, I'd check return values to handle errors. I'll do it.

Comment: UI Automation is the automation api

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Automation api looks interesting. I'll definitively invest time in near future into it. As I did not know it before, is it also workable for applications that have some anti-input protection?

Comment: Who knows? Maybe. Maybe not. Any more specifics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But the weird thing is I am not able to read/write the edit control in Delphi by using Windows apis.

pywinauto uses standard Win32 API, so anything it can do, you can do in Delphi.

[pywinauto is open source](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/), so you can see how `ctrl.ClickInput()` and `ctrl.SetEditText()` are implemented.

`ctrl.ClickInput()` calls [`SetCursorPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`ctrl.SetEditText()` sends an [`EM_SETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to highlight the Edit control's current text, and then sends an [`EM_REPLACESEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to replace the highlighted text with new text.  My guess would be that the Edit control's "anti-input protection" might not be blocking those messages.

Something else to note, pywinauto tends to call `WaitForInputIdle()` and `Sleep()` after performing actions in other windows/processes, to give the target some time to process the actions.  That may be a factor in "anti-input protection" trying to weed out automated code but allow user activity.

> SetForegroundWindow(EditControlHandle); // Works, the application will be brought to front, the edit control will be focused

I have never heard of `SetForegroundWindow()` bringing a child control into the foreground.  Even if it does, `SetForegroundWindow()` has many restrictions that will likely prevent your app from setting a foreground window anyway.

> SetFocus(EditControlHandle); // Nothing happens, if it is focused at another edit control of the form currently

If you want to change the input focus to a window in another process, you have to attach your calling thread to the target window's thread using `AttachThreadInput()`.  This is clearly stated in the [`SetFocus()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> SetText(EditControlHandle, 'Hello world'); // Nothing happens

`SetText()` is not a standard Win32 API function.  Do you mean [`SetWindowText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead?  `SetWindowText()` cannot set the text of a window in another process, the documentation says as much.

Or is `SetText()` a wrapper for `WM_SETTEXT`?  A control that has "anti-input protection" is likely to block `WM_SETTEXT` messages that it does not generate itself.

> SendKeys32.SendKey('Hello world', {Wait=}True); // Nothing happens

SendKeys merely puts keystrokes into the system's keyboard queue, letting Windows deliver them to the focused window.  This should work, since an app cannot differentiate between user entered keystrokes and SendKeys-injected keystrokes.  Unless the target app is hooking `SendKeys()` and `keybd_event()` to detect injected keystrokes, that is.

Have you tried this code yet?

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_27432926.html

> SendMessage(EditControlHandle, Ord('H'), WM_KEYDOWN, 0); // Nothing happens
>   SendMessage(EditControlHandle, Ord('H'), WM_KEYUP, 0);

You have the `Msg` and `wParam` parameter values backwards. `Ord('H')` is 72, which is the `WM_POWER` message.  Edit controls do not care about electricity state changes.

You also need to include some flags when sending these messages:

```
var
  ScanCode: UINT;

ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(Ord('H'), MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
SendMessage(EditControlHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, Ord('H'), ScanCode shl 16);
SendMessage(EditControlHandle, WM_KEYUP, Ord('H'), (ScanCode shl 16) or $C0000001);
```

> FocusedThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessID(ExternalAppMainWindowHandle, nil);

If you use `AttachThreadInput()`, you need to attach to the thread that owns the Edit control, so use the Edit control's HWND, not its parent HWND.

> if AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadID, FocusedThreadID, {Attach=}True) then // Returns False

What version of Windows are you using?  On Vista and later, `GetLastError()` returns a valid error code if `AttachThreadInput()` fails.

**Update**: a rough translation of the pywinauto source code for the script you showed would look something like this in Delphi:

```
uses
  ..., Windows;

procedure WaitGuiThreadIdle(wnd: HWND);
var
  process_id: DWORD;
  hprocess: THandle;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, process_id);
  hprocess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, process_id);
  WaitForInputIdle(hprocess, 1000);
  CloseHandle(hprocess);
end;

function SndMsgTimeout(wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): DWORD_PTR;
begin
  SendMessageTimeout(wnd, Msg, wParam, lParam, SMTO_NORMAL, 1, @Result);
end;

var
  wnd, ctrl, cur_foreground: HWND;
  cur_fore_thread, control_thread: DWORD;
  r: TRect;
  input: array[0..1] of TInput;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // hwnd = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(class_name='TLoginForm')[0]

  wnd := FindWindow('TLoginForm', nil);

  // window = helper.window_(handle=hwnd)
  // ctrl = window[2]   # the second control is the edit control I want to access

  wnd := GetWindow(wnd, GW_CHILD);
  ctrl := GetWindow(wnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);

  // ctrl.ClickInput()  # focus the control

  cur_foreground := GetForegroundWindow();
  if ctrl <> cur_foreground then
  begin
    cur_fore_thread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(cur_foreground, nil);
    control_thread := GetWindowThreadProcessId(ctrl, nil);
    if cur_fore_thread <> control_thread then
    begin
      AttachThreadInput(cur_fore_thread, control_thread, True);
      SetForegroundWindow(ctrl);
      AttachThreadInput(cur_fore_thread, control_thread, False);
    end
    else
      SetForegroundWindow(ctrl);

    WaitGuiThreadIdle(ctrl);
    Sleep(60);
  end; 

  GetWindowRect(ctrl, r);
  SetCursorPos((r.Width div 2) + r.Left, (r.Height div 2) + r.Top);
  Sleep(10);

  for I := 0 to 1 do
  begin
    input[I].Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
    input[I].mi.dx := 0;
    input[I].mi.dy := 0;
    input[I].mi.mouseData := 0;
    input[I].mi.dwFlags := 0;
    input[I].mi.time := 0;
    input[I].mi.dwExtraInfo := 0;
  end;

  if GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON) = 0 then
  begin
    input[0].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    input[1].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
  end else
  begin
    input[0].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
    input[1].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
  end;

  for I := 0 to 1 do
  begin
    SendInput(1, @input[I], Sizeof(TInput));
    Sleep(10);
  end;

  // ctrl.SetEditText('Hello world')  # text can be changed expectedly

  SndMsgTimeout(ctrl, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);
  WaitGuiThreadIdle(ctrl);
  Sleep(0);

  SndMsgTimeout(ctrl, EM_REPLACESEL, 1, LPARAM(PChar('Hello world')));
  WaitGuiThreadIdle(ctrl);
  Sleep(0);
end;
```

Comment: Oh, yes, they have not block `EM_REPLACESEL`. You made my day. Thanks for providing great valuable information. I tried `AttachThreadInput()` on Win7 (x64). I use FindWindow('TLoginForm', nil) to get the window handle.

Comment: I added a Delphi translation of the script code for you.